# J2EE application uses wrong class from library

Tags: java, maven

In my J2EE (jdk1.8) application I am using :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.01</version>
</dependency>
```

I am using also an API (Javadocx)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.javadocx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javadocx</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

which makes a call to DocumentBuilder.parse() method :

```
 DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
 baseDocument = dBuilder.parse(baseTemplateDocumentTStream);
```

The problem is that, when packaged with maven, the application uses DocumentBuilder from Jdk 1.8, not the one from xml-apis.1.4.01
So how can I make my app to use DocumentBuilder from xml-apis instead of Jdk 1.8?

Comment: I bet they have different package names? Have you checked that?

Comment: they have the same package names

Comment: Can you tell where they are coming from because they not in central... self created ?   Apart from that if they have the same package name there is really something wrong!!

Comment: Please add the output of the `mvn dependency:tree`